# QGIS Plugin to add point to map without creating a file

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am looking for a QGIS Plugin to add a point to the map by entering it's coordinates. The point should only be there temporarily (as long as the QGIs project is open) and not be saved in a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"QuickWKT" by Alessandro Pasotti is the simplest way to create a point layer knowing it's coordinates

"New Memory Layer" plugin by Boris Jurgiel allow you to create a memory layer that you can edit adding point features

probably there are others that I don't know ;)

regards

Comment: QuickWKT is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!